# How to list all attributes of "-class" in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am running powershell command below

```
Get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldis
```

I want to list all other attributes for `-class`. How can I do it?

I tried `get-wmiobject | get-member`, it was asking me to input a class value which I dont know what options I have.

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-WMIObject -List| Where{$_.name -match "^Win32_"} | Sort Name | Format-Table Name
```

Comment: `get-cimclass` can do it  also

Comment: duly noted. I will add that to my repository.